# Sound card and integrated sound

Tags: windows-xp, audio, sound-card

I'm using winXP, and I have sound card 5.1(, also integrated sound on motherboard)..
Is it possible, with some software to be able to switch between sound card and integrated sound ?
I have 5.1 surround system and also I want(sometimes) to use headphones(with mic)..
My surround system don't have connector for headphones, also a  connector for mic is a problem..

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has a handy preference in the sound settings where you can choose your default audio device. As far as I remember, there is a similar setting in Windows XP in the sound settings in the control panel.

You can probably reach it by right-clicking on that loudspeaker symbol in the notification area (bottom righ corner of the screen) and selecting 'sound properties' or soemthing like that.

Sorry for not being more specific, but I haven't used XP for quite a while.